# Cost and Usage by Instance without manual tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

### Question

I'm trying to get the cost of all instances, be that a db instance or web app, for a time period.

However at the moment I can only seem to retrieve the cost by service when using the AWS Cost Explorer.

Eventually I'm looking to access these costs via the Costs API automatically in a plug and play kind of way, so I wont know what tags have been applied or which ones I should use, thus why I want to avoid using tagging if possible.

### Question

Is there a way to do this without manually assigning each instance a tag, and then grouping by said tag.

Comment: @user1529891 Let just say the tentant does not belong to me, however I do have access to it's billing api. I have had no input on how the resources have been created, however I still need to access cost by instance.

Comment: Did you try poking it with awscli and get-cost-and-usage method (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html). You should be able to achieve that.